# CALayer drawInContext vs addSublayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, calayer, cgcontext

How can I use both of these in the same UIView correctly?

I have one custom subclassed CALayer in which I draw a pattern within drawInContext

I have a another in which I set an overlay PNG image as the contents.

I have a third which is just a background.

How do I overlay all 3 of these items?

```
[self.layer addSublayer:bottomLayer];    // this line is the problem

[squaresLayer drawInContext:viewContext];
[self.layer addSublayer:imgLayer];
```

The other 2 by themselves draw correctly if I do them in that order.  No matter where I try and put bottomLayer, it always prevents squaresLayer from drawing. The reason I need 3 layers is I intend to animate the colors in the background and custom layers.  The top layer is just a graphical overlay.

Comment: Several questions: Are you sure the layer is not being drawn?  Or is it being drawn but not giving you the results you are looking for?  How do the layers overlap?  Is it necessary for these layers to all be in the same view, or could you split one of them into a different view?

Comment: Hi, well, they SHOULD be able to be in the same UIView, I suppose I could use subviews, seems like a bit much to use separate views just to composite layers.  However I did come up with a solution by making 2 custom layers.  Anything added to self.layer via "addSublayer" seems to draw on top of anything drawn via "drawInContext" which is drawing straight to the context of the view's .layer. Ok so, figuring that out I just rendered 2 layers to that context and added the imgLayer on top.  Works fine, as for animation wound up using an NSTimer refreshing the view, which runs drawInContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well paste the code in in case anyone is trying to animate stacked CALayers that have their own internal draw routines

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [imgLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

    CGFloat w = [self.blockViewDelegate w];
    CGFloat h = [self.blockViewDelegate h];

    CGFloat wb = w/4;
    CGFloat hb = h/4;

    CGContextRef viewContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Layers

    [bottomLayer sizes:wb :hb :1];
    bottomLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);
    bottomLayer.opaque = NO;

    [topLayer sizes:wb :hb :0];
    topLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);
    topLayer.opaque = NO;

    // Overlay

    imgLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);
    imgLayer.opaque = NO;
    imgLayer.opacity = 1.0f;

    UIImage *overlay = [self.blockViewDelegate image];
    CGImageRef img = overlay.CGImage;
    imgLayer.contents = (id)img;

    // Add layers

    [bottomLayer drawInContext:viewContext];
    [topLayer drawInContext:viewContext];
    [self.layer addSublayer:imgLayer];

}
```

blockViewDelegate is where I am storing width, height, and image information, it is the controller for this UIView.

topLayer and bottomLayer are of a custom UIView subclass which draw some shapes in the view with variable color information.  Later on in my animation I just run "setNeedsDisplay" repeatedly with a timer and this routine repeats, the layers re-draw using updated parameters.